# Lookup and replace in r

Tags: r, lookup

I have a column1 containing the same value which is an "a" character.
I would like to rename all similar values in column b by "a_bis"

So basically in my dataset the value data[1,2] needs to be replaced by "a_bis"

```
a = c("a", "a", "a")
b = c("a", "b", "c")
data = data.frame(a,b)
```

Comment: `data$b[data$b == "a"] <- "a_bis"` ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ifelse`

```
data$b <- with(data, ifelse(b==a, paste(b, 'bis',sep="_"), b))
data$b
#[1] "a_bis" "b"     "c"
```

If this is specific about character "a"

```
data$b <- with(data, ifelse(b=="a", "a_bis", b))
```

#### data

```
data = data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: @MarcLacombe I noticed that you have `factor` columns,  Use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to get those columns as `character` and it will work